# ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options after update @vue/cli-service

Tags: vue.js

I have an error after run serve Vue.Js 3. Before do that, i upgrade my vue/cli-service to 5.0.8.

The error is like this:

```
ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

    at validateOptions (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:32:11)
    at new ProgressPlugin (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:62:3)
    at new Progress (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/progress-webpack-plugin/index.js:25:21)
    at new progressPlugin (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/progress-webpack-plugin/index.js:127:10)
    at /Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack-chain/src/Plugin.js:14:18
    at module.exports.toConfig (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack-chain/src/Plugin.js:78:22)
    at /Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack-chain/src/Config.js:129:63
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.toConfig (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/webpack-chain/src/Config.js:129:40)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (/Volumes/USERNAME/My Project/APPS/apps-backend-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:277:34)
```

i have try to `npm update`, but its still error.

Comment: Have you read the migration guide from v4 to v5? I believe that v5 uses WebPack v5 and it could be incompatible with some v4 plugins. Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again?

Comment: no i dont follow the instruction. I tried that, but there is still error. But when i run ```npm run build``` its success but it say ```[DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_NORMAL_MODULE_LOADER_HOOK] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader was moved to NormalModule.getCompilationHooks(compilation).loader```

Comment: This error message obviously signals that there is something obsolete in your setup. Instead of trying to fix it - why don't you try to create a new empty Vue CLI project and after testing that it works you can simply move your old code into this new project?

Comment: Ok, it fix now. I create new project and copy the devDevepencies to my current project. And also there is have depedencies conflict, and after uninstall that depedencies, its all run normally now. Thanks for your advice. @IVOGELOV